# Change Selection Field odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to generate different selection choices depending on other field in the Model. I am working in Odoo 8. 
Below is the code :

My Model: (test.py)

```
type = fields.Selection(selection='_get_selection', string='Type')

@api.onchange('role_name')
def _get_selection(self):
    choise = []
    if self.role_name == 'primary':
        choise.append(('unit','Unit Case'))

    if self.role_name == 'reserve':
        choise.append(('res','Reserve Case'))

    return choise
```

The View: (template.xml)

```
<field name="type" widget="selection"/>
```

But i don't see any values in Selection Field.

Please Help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```
@api.model
def _get_selection(self):
    #DO SOMETHING
    return choise
type = fields.Selection(selection=_get_selection, string='Type')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example from 'account.invoice' in Odoo 8:

```
@api.model
def _get_reference_type(self):
    return [('none', _('Free Reference'))]

reference_type = fields.Selection('_get_reference_type', string='Payment Reference',
    required=True, readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]},
    default='none')
```

This should help you in resolving the issue.

Comment: What is the error that you get? What is the behaviour when you try what is in the above code? A simple "it does not work" doesn't help us solve the problem. Try to be more specific.

Comment: Hi Bhavya, First of all before answering the question, you should know what is asked in the question. I specified depends on other field of the model. so it should have @api.onchange(),which i have written.  secondly, i do not get any error, only the selection field is empty (i.e. no options seen on the selection).